# GUI for Berkeley DB

Tags: java, user-interface, berkeley-db

I'm using Berkeley DB Java edition, via the DPL interface.
I want to ask if someone knows about any GUI library that could make it easy to browse the data saved in the database.

I know that BDB documentation says that the metadata about the stored entities is not saved in any place and therefore only the person who have written the data can know what are the types of the classes that would be returned from there. That's why I'm searching for a library (not a complete program) that would be included to the main project and so it would know the types of my classes and would be able to show the data correctly.

p.s. I've found this [bdb-browser](http://code.google.com/p/bdb-browser/) but it seems like a dead project.

*Update:*
So far I've found a GUI that shows the statistics gathered for the BDB via the JMX. Here is how to use it: http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/berkeley-db/je/jconsole/JConsole-plugin.html
Still searching for *data* browser...

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/bdb/create/get_started_bdb.html

Comment: @phreed, very nice, is it capable of presenting composite keys and values?

Comment: I do not know I am still trying to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You could try [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/).

DbVisualizer doesn't directly support the Berkeley DB, but does provide JDBC drivers for many databases,

Answer (score 1):

You can use Execute Query to connect Berkeley DB. Its is a free software. You can get the distribution from http://executequery.org

Comment: I see that in ExecuteQuery I can define a connection just via a JDBC, how does that helps me with Berkeley DB?

Comment: You need to compile jdbc driver for berkely and add it to ExecuteQuery first. Then it will be possible to access database using JDBC URL like "jdbc:sqlite:/C:\mydatabase" where "mydatabase" is the database file.

Comment: How exactly can I `compile jdbc driver for berkely` ? It is not clear to me how `sqlite` is related to `BerkeleyDB`.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html#DoesBerkeleyDBsupportJDBC points to the sqlite JDBC driver

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extremely simple browser. Needs to be compiled though.

https://github.com/ferruccio/bdbvu

Comment: Google code is down. Most probably this is the same:
  https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bdbvu
  https://github.com/ferruccio/bdbvu

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and didn't find anything.

I don't think you're going to have a lot of luck looking for a data browser, because the format of the value in each database entry is going to be variable.  For example, it might be primitive data, data written out by the default Java serialization, or a custom format for an instance of a class which implements [Externalizable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html).

Comment: For the DPL there is a need just to have the entity classes on the CLASS_PATH. I've written a simple swing app that displays the data itself, but if is still in "alfa" status. After I'll have time to finish, I'll publish it.